# MFC SetRegistryKey opposite function? What am I missing?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, visual-studio-2017, registry

In my app the default Registry key is created called:

```
SetRegistryKey(_T("Trains"));
```

It places that "root" key value like so:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Trains
```

My app saves all the window info and other data in subkeys under Trains. I have a "reset" menu item that when the user activates, I would like to delete that "root" key and all the subkeys under it.

If I'm in registry editor, it is simply a right click and delete....and blamo, all gone.

I've read other threads here and on Google and there seems to be multiple ways to do this.... I've tried  DelRegTree with little success and I'm unclear why this process is so cumbersome to do with multiple functions and recursion to find all the keys, delete them, then remove the root key.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwinapp-class?view=msvc-160#delregtree

I've tried `DelRegTree(\\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE, _T("Trains"));` but that doesn't work. How should I approach this seemingly easy task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`SHDeleteKey()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-shdeletekeya). You can use `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`  for the first argument and specify the key path (from that) in the second:

```cpp
#include <shlwapi.h>
LSTATUS status = SHDeleteKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, _T("SOFTWARE\\Trains"));
```

You will need to include "Shwlapi.lib" in your link.

(Note: Calling the `DelRegTree` member of `CWinApp` *may* also work, if you use the same arguments; but you can't add the `\\SOFTWARE` part to the first argument – that will have to be included in the key path/name.)

Comment: Excellent, that worked right out of the box! Just one question, will this work as far back as WinXP? I'm running Win10. I recall reading a few bits that some things only work from Vista forward...I'm not concerned too much about XP, 2K .. but I know some people still use it...for whatever their reasons may be. Thanks!

Comment: @Kittmaster The linked documentation page says: ***Minimum supported client*** *Windows 2000 Professional, Windows XP [desktop apps only]* (I use it in an application that is still used on Windows XP.)

Comment: Perfect, this solution is very simple and elegant. Accepted Solution. @Adrian > Thank you!